# Get combination cross coupling between two an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a datatable name `dt` with columns like this:

```
A1     B1     A2    B2.
```

This mean I have array:

```
A = { A1, A2 }

B = { B1, B2 }
```

Note: about eight arrays: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. I must pair like:

```
A vs B

C vs D

E vs F
....
```

I want divide pair between two arrays like:

```
A1    pair with     B2.

A2    pair with     B1.
```

I tried with code:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    firstSumValCombinate = numRows * (Convert.ToDouble(r["A0_1"]) / Convert.ToDouble(r["B0_2"]));
    averageFirst = (firstSumValCombinate * numKillProc) / 2;
    ......
    finalResultFirst = (many manipulate) * firstSumValCombinate;

    secondSumValCombinate = numRows * (Convert.ToDouble(r["A0_2"]) / Convert.ToDouble(r["B0_1"]));
    averageFirst = (secondSumValCombinate * numKillProc) / 2;
    finalResultSecond = (many manipulate) * secondSumValCombinate;
}
```

I have many the variable `number + "SumValCombinate"`

And almost it similar when calculator.

It only changes `r[columnsName]`, so I must write many code.

Comment: Please provide more information about "what is not working". Exception ?

Comment: It does not return any error. This code I think to run but seem it is not working. I think I lost anything, so it was not working. So, I post to hope anyone can have any method to do this better my method to resolve the problem.

Comment: These are just little code fragments. If you provide a Minimal Compilable Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) maybe people can help you a bit more.

Comment: Why are you using the same variable to store all the values ? After the loop, `firstSumValCombinate` will hold the division of the last row only.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I have two arrays. A = { 1, 2} and B = { 3, 4 }. I want results like 1/4 and 2/3.

Comment: Where do you wan to store the division result ? array ? It seems `firstSumValCombinate ` is a single double variable. How can it hold all the results ?

Comment: @user3185569 I added result of variable to List<>. Have you any idea better not using List<>? Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you're doing that ? Edit your question and show more of how you're adding the result to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Complete example of a working code that matches what you said storing the results in 2 arrays:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A0_1", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("A0_2", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("B0_1", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("B0_2", typeof(double));

dt.Rows.Add(4.0, 10.0, 2.0, 2.0);
dt.Rows.Add(20.0, 30.0, 10.0, 5.0);

double[] resultsFirst = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
double[] resultsSecond = new double[dt.Rows.Count];

int index = 0;
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    resultsFirst[index] = r.Field<double>("A0_1") / r.Field<double>("B0_2");
    resultsSecond[index] = r.Field<double>("A0_2") / r.Field<double>("B0_1");
    index++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < resultsFirst.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"First = { resultsFirst[i] } ** Second = { resultsSecond[i] }");
}
```

**Results :**

```
First = 2 ** Second = 5
First = 4 ** Second = 3
```

Comment: It should be that. I updated my question why I must do this. It's true with two arrays. But many arrays it will have more code and fail.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing the problem that you have is that you could not store all of the results. So the solution is just to have the result stored in `List<double>`.

```
List<double> firstSumValCombinate = new List<double>();
List<double> secondSumValCombinate = new List<double>();
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
   firstSumValCombinate.Add(Convert.ToDouble(r["A0_1"]) / Convert.ToDouble(r["B0_2"]));
   secondSumValCombinate.Add(Convert.ToDouble(r["A0_2"]) / Convert.ToDouble(r["B0_1"]));
}
```